# detecting multiple html tags with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension which would read the current page and detect specific html/xml tags out of it :

For example if my current page contains the following tags or data :

```
some random text here and there

<investmentAccount acctType="individual" uniqueId="1629529524">
<accountName>state bank of america</accountName>
<accountHolder>rahul raina</accountHolder>
<balance balType="totalBalance">
<curAmt curCode="USD">516545.84</curAmt>
</balance>
<asOf localFormat="MMM dd, yyyy">2013-08-31T00:00:00</asOf>
<holdingList>
<holding holdingType="mutualFund" uniqueId="-2044388005">
<description>Active Global Equities</description>
<value curCode="USD">159436.01</value>
</holding>
<holding holdingType="mutualFund" uniqueId="-556870249">
<description>Passive Non-US Equities</description> 
<value curCode="USD">72469.76</value>
</holding>
</holdingList>
<transactionList/>
</investmentAccount>
</site>
some data 123

<site name="McKinsey401k">
<investmentAccount acctType="individual" uniqueId="1629529524">
<accountName>rahuk</accountName>
<accountHolder>rahuk</accountHolder>
<balance balType="totalBalance">
<curAmt curCode="USD">516545.84</curAmt>
</balance>
<asOf localFormat="MMM dd, yyyy">2013-08-31T00:00:00</asOf>
<holdingList>
<holding holdingType="mutualFund" uniqueId="1285447255">
<description>Special Sits. Aggr. Long-Term</description>
<value curCode="USD">101944.69</value>
</holding>
<holding holdingType="mutualFund" uniqueId="1721876694">
<description>Special Situations Moderate $</description>
<value curCode="USD">49444.98</value>
</holding>
</holdingList>
<transactionList/>
</investmentAccount>
</site>
```

So I need to identify say  tag and print the text between the starting and ending tag i.e : "State bank of america" and "rahukk"

So this is what I have done till now:

```
    function countString(document_r,a,b) {
var test = document_r.body; 
var text = typeof test.textContent == 'string'? test.textContent : test.innerText; 
var testRE = text.match(a+"(.*)"+b);
return testRE[1];

}



chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: "XML DETAILS>>>>>"+"\nAccount name is: " +countString(document,'<accountName>','</accountName>')
});
```

But this only prints the innertext of only the first tag it encounters in the page i.e "State bank of america".

What if I want to print only "rahukk" which is the innertext of last  tag in the page or both.

How do I print the innertext of last tag it encounters in the page or how does it print all the tags ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : The document above itself is an HTML page i have just put the contents of the page

UPDATE : So I did some here and there from the suggestions below and the best I could reach by this code :

```
function countString(document_r) {


var test = document_r.body; 
var text = test.innerText; 

var tag = "accountName";
var regex = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\/" + tag + ">";
var regexg = new RegExp(regex,"g");
var testRE = text.match(regexg);
return testRE;
}

chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: "XML DETAILS>>>>>"+"\nAccount name is: " +countString(document)
});
```

But this gave me :

> XML DETAILS>>>>> Retirement Program (Profit-Sharing
>   Retirement Plan (PSRP) and Money Purchase Pension Plan
>   (MPPP)),Retirement Program (Profit-Sharing
>   Retirement Plan (PSRP) and Money Purchase Pension Plan
>   (MPPP)),Retirement Program (Profit-Sharing
>   Retirement Plan (PSRP) and Money Purchase Pension Plan
>   (MPPP))

This again because the same XML was present in the page 3 times and What I want is that regex to match only from the last XML and I don't want the tag names too.

So my desired output would be:

> XML DETAILS>>>>> Retirement Program (Profit-Sharing
>   Retirement Plan (PSRP) and Money Purchase Pension Plan
>   (MPPP))

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use `getElementsByTagName`?

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern like this: `<accountName>(.*?)<\/accountName>`

```
var tag = "accountName";
var regex = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\/" + tag + ">";
var testRE = text.match(regex);
```

=> testRE contains all your matches, in case of tag=accountName it contains "state bank of america" and "rahukk"

**UPDATE**

According to [this page](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml) to receive all matches, instead of only the first one, you smust add a "g" flag to the match pattern.

> "g: The global search flag makes the RegExp search for a pattern
>   throughout the string, creating an array of all occurrences it can
>   find matching the given pattern." found [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: sorry didn't get you :(

Comment: I tried this @fen89 but it will only print one...!! for more info please look at the comments of my talk with jordan-gray below. :)

Comment: To receive all matches, instead of only the first one, you smust add a "g" flag to the match pattern. See my updated answer @rahul888

Comment: hi @fen89 . Thanks for the reply, but I had already used that in my code, as you can see in my updated post..!!

But what I want is to match to occur only below the specific line in the page.

Answer (score 1):

you match method is not global.

```
var regex = new RegExp(a+"(.*)"+b, "g");
text.match(regex);
```

Comment: Yea.. You are matching against textContent which doesn't contain the tags.

Comment: I want to print the innercontent of the tags that i want to match

Comment: For that you have match the tags first ryt ??

Comment: textContent or innerText rips off the tags and present you only with the content. You will not get a match for your tags. Check your console for document.body.innerText / textContent and document.body.innerHTML.

Comment: arvind my code does the job actually. But it only prints the contents of the very first tag in the page. what if there are multiple same tags and I want to print the last or all...??

Answer (score 1):

If the full XML string is valid, you can parse it into an XML document using the [`DOMParser.parseFromString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Parsing_XML):

```
var xmlString = '<root>[Valid XML string]</root>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
```

Then you can get a list of tags with a specified name directly:

```
var found = doc.getElementsByTagName('tagName');
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/KL8AN/) using the XML you provided, with two minor tweaks—I had to add a `root` element and an opening tag for the first `site`.

Comment: Jordan that is a indeed a very good approach, but as I told my complete document contains a lot of other stuff than this xml only. :(

Comment: @rahul888 Eugh, I see. :( Could you perhaps post an anonymised example of the full document?

Comment: @rahul888 (If the XML is segregated into a specific part of the full document, you might be able to extract it cleanly into a string.)

Comment: it is a very big document. with lots of data best I can give you is : 

[link](http://pastebin.com/4m3vtcM9)

Comment: @rahul888 Are the XML code bits wrapped in a particular HTML structure, e.g. something with a common class name? Could they be?

Comment: XML code always starts with, <site name="XXXXX">
and ends with </site>

I can successfully extract this site name "XXXXX" from the page :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39906/discussion-between-jordan-gray-and-rahul888)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for your task (besides, read [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for why it's not a good idea!). You can do this completely via javascript:

```
var tag = "section";
var targets = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
for (var i = targets.length; i > 0; i--) {
    console.log(targets[i].innerText);
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work because actually I am not working on XHTML document, but on a dump that is probably string . Confused though

Comment: That's no problem at all. You could create an element based on your string and do that logic there as well. And if that's not working you still shouldn't do it via regexp but with an XML/HTML parser instead.

Comment: I still can't make much of your method mate :(